# What regex will match repeat patterns in the string below?

Tags: regex, string

I have a small problem with regex. I need to parse all words from string behind:

> word - word2, word3, word4

Have tried to solve, but it is returning only last iteration

```
(\w+) - ((\w+)[, ]{0,2})+
```

https://regex101.com/r/2Uot2M/1

Thank you for any help.

P.S: I can't just match all words like (\w+). I need to match string with the format above.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: @Simon I'm not going to do the work for him.

Comment: Well, if you use your regex in .NET, you already have what you need, [the values are in Group 3 capture collection](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cw%2b%29+-+%28%28%5cw%2b%29%5b%2c+%5d%7b0%2c2%7d%29%2b&i=apple+-+malum%2c+bla), see *Table* tab and expand `$3` captures. Or, a [PCRE solution will look uglier](https://regex101.com/r/Igo1bs/1), `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\w+ - (?:\w+[, ]{0,2})+$))\W*\K\w+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the answer. Your PCRE is working fine :) I will try to simplify it. Can you post it as answer? I'll mark it.

Comment: Well, it took time to explain, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PCRE regex library and you need to pre-validate a string before extracting words from it, you may use the following pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\w+ - (?:\w+[, ]{0,2})+$))\W*\K\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Igo1bs/1).

**How it works**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=\w+ - (?:\w+[, ]{0,2})+$))` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) start of a string (`^`) that is followed with the following pattern:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `-`  - a hyphen enclosed with single spaces
  - `(?:\w+[, ]{0,2})+` - 1+ occurrences of:

    - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
    - `[, ]{0,2}` - 0 to 2 occurrences of a space or comma
  - `$` - end of string
- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from Group 0 (whole match) buffer
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to capture each word into a separate capture group, you can just use this regex:
`(\w+)`

This captures all substrings with one or more word characters (letters or numbers). It will ignore the whitespace and punctuation. On Regex 101 it captures 'word', 'word2', 'word3', and 'word4' into separate capture groups

Helpful link on word characters: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

Helpful link on quantifiers ('+' is a quantifier): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the answer. But i need to parse strictly with the format. I can't just match all words :)

Comment: @Rob, added some more explanation & helpful links.

Comment: Links for answers are not allowed on SO and will get your answer closed. Form your own answer here or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob Hi, just want to get advice, not a solution. Calm down, man :)

Comment: @kpa6 Nice. This is a great place but violating Stack Overflow policy and rules is never a good thing.

Comment: @Rob I will read it again, excuse me. Now I just want to get good advice to resolve the issue.

Comment: @kpa6, are you trying to capture the comma-separated words into a separate capture group? Give this a try: ((?:\w+\,? ?){0,}) It captures multiple comma-separated words (that may or may not have a space afterwards). I use a non-capture group to surround the word + comma & space.

Comment: @rmdelgad Thanks for the answer. Yea, i'm trying to capture word before and words comma-separated after the dash in separate groups. Just tried your regex sadly it not work, but i'll try to look around him. May be i'll find the solution near.

Comment: Ah. Ok then I think the solution is this: `(\w+) - ((?:\w+\,? ?){0,})` This will capture the first word in one capture group and the words after the dash in another capture group.

Answer (score 1):

No validation needed except with first `word-word`.
Using the \G anchor and a branch reset, will fill an array
where the `words` *collect* in capture group 1.

`(?|(\w+)[ ]*-[ ]*(?=\w)|(?!^)\G[ ]*,?[ ]*(\w+))`

https://regex101.com/r/deZq5u/1

Note no need for BOS or EOS anchor's which are crutches.
This will find valid matches mid-string as it should.

[Formatted and tested](http://www.regexformat.com)

*(Note the `# Optional spaces, single comma, spaces` will always match

either a space or a comma or both, even though optional, and is a required

separator. This is because the `\w+` clause will not leave any behind.)*

```
 (?|                           # Branch reset
      ( \w+ )                       # (1), First word
      [ ]* - [ ]*                   # qualified with a dash,
      (?= \w )                      # then a lookahead for next word
   |                              # or,
      (?! ^ )                       # Reset \G at BOS
      \G                            # Anchor, second or more match
      [ ]* ,? [ ]*                  # Optional spaces, single comma, spaces
      ( \w+ )                       # (1), Second or more word
 )                             # End branch reset
```